# Redondear AVG de un PIVOT con columnas dinámicas en sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

estoy tratando de hacer un reporte con columnas dinámicas, por lo tanto para lograrlo estoy usando Pivot en la consulta SQL, pero me encontré con un problema, al momento de promediar las notas con AVG me da como resultado demasiados decimales y solo necesito 1. Dejaré la consulta que tengo y el resultado en una imagen.

```
DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max);  
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);  
  
 
SELECT @Pivot_Column= COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ QUOTENAME(tab.Nombre) FROM  
(select distinct (convert(varchar, isnull(grp.GrupoId, 0)) + '|' + cri.Nombre + ' ' + convert(varchar, nota.PorcentajeCri) + '%|' + convert(varchar, cri.CriterioID)) as Nombre 
from Emp_PlantillaCriterioAspectoNota_CS nota
inner join Emp_Criterio_CS cri on cri.CriterioID = nota.CriterioID
left join Emp_GrupoServicioPlantilla grp on grp.CriterioId = cri.CriterioID and nota.ServicioPlantillaID = grp.ServicioPlantillaId 
where nota.PlantillaID = 55)Tab
order by tab.nombre desc



 
SELECT @Query='SELECT Evaluacion, Contratista, Servicio, Instalacion, Nota, '+@Pivot_Column+',
CASE WHEN EMPRESAPRINCIPALID = 1420 THEN        
        CASE  WHEN ISNULL(NOTA, 0) = 0 THEN ''No calificado'' 
        WHEN CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0),  ISNULL(DECIMALES, 1)) AS FLOAT) < CAST(ROUND(4.0, 1) AS decimal(10,1)) THEN 
        ''No calificado''
        WHEN CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0), 1) AS decimal(10,1)) >= CAST(ROUND(4.0, 1) AS decimal(10,1))
        AND CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0), 1) AS decimal(10,1)) < CAST(ROUND(5.0, 1) AS decimal(10,1))
        THEN 
        ''Calificado con reserva''
        WHEN CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0), 1) AS decimal(10,1)) >= CAST(ROUND(5.0, 1) AS decimal(10,1))
        AND CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0), 1) AS decimal(10,1)) < CAST(ROUND(6.5, 1) AS decimal(10,1))
        THEN 
            CASE WHEN DBO.FNC_CANTIDAD_NOTAS_BAJAS_CRITERIO_EVA(ServicioPlantillaID,PlantillaID,EmpresaPrincipalId) > 0 THEN
                ''Calificado con reserva''
                ELSE
                ''Calificado''
                END
        WHEN CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0), 1) AS decimal(10,1)) >= CAST(ROUND(6.5, 1) AS decimal(10,1))
        AND CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(NOTA, 0.0), 1) AS decimal(10,1)) < CAST(ROUND(7.1, 1) AS decimal(10,1))
        THEN 
            CASE WHEN DBO.FNC_CANTIDAD_NOTAS_BAJAS_CRITERIO_EVA(ServicioPlantillaID,PlantillaID,EmpresaPrincipalId) > 0 THEN
                ''Calificado con reserva''
                ELSE
                ''Calificado con excelencia''
                END
        ELSE
            ''''
    END
END CONDICION
FROM   
(
select distinct 
servpl.Nombre Evaluacion,
emp.NombreComercial Contratista,
serv.Nombre Servicio,
ins.Nombre Instalacion,
servpl.Nota,
CAST(ISNULL(nota.NOTA, 0.0) AS decimal(10,1)) NotaPromedio,
SERVPL.ServicioPlantillaID,
SERVPL.PlantillaID,
empcont.EmpresaPrincipalId,
config.DECIMALES,
(convert(varchar, isnull(grp.GrupoPlantillaId, 0)) + ''|'' + cri.Nombre + '' '' + convert(varchar, nota.PorcentajeCri) + ''%'' + ''|'' + convert(varchar, cri.CriterioId)) as Criterio
from Emp_ServicioPlantilla_CS servpl
inner join Emp_PlantillaCriterioAspectoNota_CS nota on nota.ServicioPlantillaID = servpl.ServicioPlantillaID
inner join Emp_Criterio_CS cri on cri.CriterioID = nota.CriterioID
left join Emp_GrupoServicioPlantilla grp on grp.CriterioId = cri.CriterioID and servpl.servicioplantillaid = grp.servicioplantillaid
inner join Emp_Servicio serv on serv.ServicioId = servpl.ServicioId
inner join Emp_ServicioInstalacion servins on servins.ServicioId = serv.ServicioId
inner join Emp_Instalacion ins on ins.InstalacionIterm = servins.InstalacionIterm
inner join Emp_EmpresaContratista empcont on empcont.EmpresaContratistaId = serv.EmpresaContratistaId
inner join EMP_CONFIGURACIONNOTAEVALUACION config on config.EmpresaID = empcont.EmpresaPrincipalId
inner join Emp_Empresa emp on emp.EmpresaId = empcont.ContratistaId
where servpl.PlantillaID = 55
)Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(NotaPromedio) FOR [Criterio] IN ('+@Pivot_Column+')) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY Tab2.Contratista' 

EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```

La cual me da el siguiente resultado

[image: Pantallazo resultado]

Como se ve en la imagen hay demasiados decimales en el resultado de AVG, solo quiero tener uno, he tratado de redondearlo directamente, pero no reconoce Round ni el Cast en el Pivot ¿Cómo podría lograr el redondeo después de sacar el promedio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que la pregunta no tiene una posible ejecución, te lo voy a plantear con un pivot estático, pero la solución sería exactamente igual, con un pivot dinámico, salvo que lo tienes que montar en la salida de las columnas.

```
Create table tableSource  (Criterio varchar(100), NotaPromedio float)

insert into tableSource (Criterio, NotaPromedio)
values
('Aplicacion de Herbicidas1',25.323442),
('Aplicacion de Herbicidas2',25.323442),
('Aplicacion de Herbicidas1',25.323442),
('Aplicacion de Herbicidas1',25.323442),
('Aplicacion de Herbicidas2',25.323442),
('Aplicacion de Herbicidas1',25.323442);
```

Una simple tabla en la que voy a pivotar los dos valores.
Esto es lo que te ocurre.

```
select pvt.[Aplicacion de Herbicidas1]
     , pvt.[Aplicacion de Herbicidas2]
       from (
              select *
                     from tableSource AS t
            ) as source pivot(Avg(NotaPromedio) 
    for criterio in([Aplicacion de Herbicidas1]
                  , [Aplicacion de Herbicidas2])) pvt;
```

[image: Res1]

Esta es una solución.
Cambiar el resultado del pivote donde se aplicamos el redondeo.

```
select round(pvt.[Aplicacion de Herbicidas1],1) As [Aplicacion de Herbicidas1]
     , round(pvt.[Aplicacion de Herbicidas2],1) As [Aplicacion de Herbicidas2]
       from (
              select *
                     from tableSource AS t
            ) as source pivot(Avg(NotaPromedio) 
    for criterio in([Aplicacion de Herbicidas1]
                  , [Aplicacion de Herbicidas2])) pvt;
```

[image: Res2]

Podrías tener para la salida otra variable, que tiene las columnas a pivotar igual que `@pivot_columns` pero que tenga aplicado la función `Round`

En el for aplicas `@pivot_Columns` y en la select aplicas la otra variable  `@pivot_ColumnsRound`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, pero hice lo que me recomendaste y no me reconoce el round como una función, si no, me lo está reconociendo como una columna invalida :/

Comment: Entonces no has hecho bien el round el texto de las columnas, porque la salida del pivote se produce en la parte superior. Antes de ejecutar el exec sp_Executesql haz un print @query. En tú round deberías de tener `Round(tab2.[colxxx],1) as [colxxx] , `. Con la misma sentencia que te devuelva print, pégala en el Management Studio, y verás como te has comido algo.

Comment: Ya quedo listo :D